# mysqli Unable to initialize module

Tags: php, apache, mysqli

I am using Apache2.4 and PHP 7.1.12

In php.ini file I had mentioned -

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

It is throwing following error:

```
PHP Startup: mysqli: Unable to initialize module. Module compiled with module API=20151012 PHP compiled with module API=20160303
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `mysqli` module compiled for PHP 7.0 in PHP 7.1. As those versions have different APIs, it won't work. Obtain modules for PHP 7.1 - they usually come with PHP distribution.

Comment: I used the zipped file which contain mysqli also. I hope php7.1 should always contain the latest version. Where I will get mysqli latest version?

Comment: Watch for "alternative" php installations set in PATH environment variable. For reasons not entirely clear to me, even PHP executed as Apache module reads path and if finds some folder folder called "php" it takes it as the root of relative path.

Or make sure path in php.ini is absolute.